# How to verify if hardware acceleration is enabled?

Tags: hardware, gpu

How can I verify whether hardware acceleration is available and whether it is enabled for my video card.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you don't already have it, install `glxinfo`; in APT it's part of `mesa-utils`:

```
apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Run `glxinfo` and look for a line about `direct rendering` (another term for hardware acceleration):

```
> glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"
direct rendering: Yes
```

If it says "Yes", hardware acceleration is enabled

Comment: In the spirit of teaching a man to fish, could you post some information on what the mesa-utils package and what the glxinfo command does?

Comment: @Noah I don't actually use Ubuntu, so I know little about its packages, but [Ubuntu's package description](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/mesa-utils) says it "provides several basic GL utilities built by Mesa, including glxinfo and glxgears". [GLX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLX) is the X extension for OpenGL; `glxinfo` displays information about that extension, including the current direct rendering state

Comment: "mesa-utils"? Sounds like something Jar Jar would say :)

Comment: In FreeBSD, glxinfo is available in the "mesa-demos" package.

Comment: Technically "direct rendering" only tells you whether your program is communicating directly with the graphics card driver.  "indirect rendering" means you are communicating all 3D to the X server which then communicates with the graphics card.  I think at some point it wasn't possible to have hardware acceleration without direct rendering, but now days indirect rendering can also be accelerated.  By extension, it could also be possible to directly communicate with a driver that fakes hardware acceleration in the CPU, but i don't know of any instance of this.

Comment: @MConrad is correct, `llvmpipe` is CPU rendering, but shows as direct rendering (`glxinfo | grep "renderer"`), Either you know that the used renderer is GPU based or running `glxgears` and monitoring GPU usage with a tool like `radeontop` (for AMD) will be a better test

Comment: @untore Indeed hardware acceleration was not enabled even if glxinfo said "direct rendering: Yes" because glxgears used the CPU. After installing the Debian package firmware-misc-nonfree, the issue was fixed and it did not display "llvmpipe" anymore.