# Firefox slow + graphics issues

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, graphics, pop-os

I recently switched from Windows to Linux (Pop!_OS). Although I'm very pleased with Pop!_OS there are a few problems that I couldn't fix yet:

Google Maps/Earth is very slow on Firefox. On Maps you don't even get 3D-View and zooming is not smooth.

Browser-Games like slitherdotio and Happy Wheels lag and have graphical artifacts.

[image]

(This "Play"-Button e.g. has this weird corrupted-looking background)

I hope you can help me out.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: The Terminal says the following if you type "lspci":

00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex

00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse IOMMU

00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge

00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge

00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge

00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge

00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge

00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge

00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge

00:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge

00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge

00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]

00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge

00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 0

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 1

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 2

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 3

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 4

00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 5

00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 6

00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 7

01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron/Crucial Technology Device 5403 (rev 03)

02:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ee

02:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43eb

02:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43e9

03:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea

2a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

2b:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Upstream Port of PCI Express Switch (rev c5)

2c:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Downstream Port of PCI Express Switch

2d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 22 (rev c5)

2d:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device ab28

2e:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function

2f:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP

2f:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP

2f:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller

2f:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller

Comment: It might be an issue with acceleration. If the kernel driver cannot properly handle your hardware, then you might be missing hardware acceleration. You can [verify if hardware acceleration is enabled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/963/how-to-verify-if-hardware-acceleration-is-enabled#964). Another option, to keep things slow but get rid of artifacts is to [disable acceleration in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1106854). Note that it is not Firefox's fault, the issue is at the kernel level and you will need the appropriate driver/options.

Comment: Chromium works flawlessly so I think the problem is Firefox.

Comment: Chromium has an integrated black list of buggy graphic drivers. When it finds one of those, it works around it.  The problem is still the buggy driver, not Firefox. Other applications might have issues with it. You might want to tell us a bit more about your graphics hardware. The output from `lspci` is a good starting point.

Comment: https://imgur.com/Zq3FZH8

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: sorry the whole text was too long for one comment.

Comment: Questions go like this: you ask something, and people may ask you to provide more information. The additional information should not go into the comments, but be readily available in the question. So, usually you edit your question, add the output (formatted) and everybody (now and in the future, for people with related problems) can get all information at once.