# Will Disabling a Discrete Graphics Card Improve GUI Performance on Linux (XWindow/Wayland)?

Tags: linux, wayland, gpu

I'm considering disabling the discrete GPU in my laptop to potentially improve GUI performance on Linux, specifically using XWindow or Wayland.
 Given the power efficiency of integrated graphics, I'm curious if they might offer a smoother or more stable experience due to possibly better driver support.

Has anyone tried this approach and observed any notable differences in GUI responsiveness or performance?
Insights on configurations or adjustments that enhance the experience would also be valuable.
Looking for practical experiences or technical insights on the impact of GPU selection on Linux GUI performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have integrated graphics, the whole point of adding discrete graphics is to get better video acceleration.

The only way that disabling the discrete graphics would help is if the hardware is broken or the driver for it is broken.  If the driver is broken, perhaps you are using the wrong driver.  You didn't mention what discrete graphics you have, or which driver you are using, so this can't be addressed.  With no driver, the discrete graphics is probably already disabled.

Assuming a working driver, the only reason to disable discrete graphics is to save power.  The reason discrete uses more power in the first place is that it uses the additional power to enhance graphics and improve responsiveness and performance.

Answer (score 0):

you did not mention what make/model of the discrete gpu, nor your laptop model nor your cpu make/model.

***would disabling a discrete gpu in the bios in the hopes that using cpu-graphics would perform better:*** probably not, unless it's a late model intel/amd cpu with whatever UHD graphics that would be better than some older model nvidia/amd gpu but this is highly unlikely in a laptop, could be possible in a home built pc.

[How to verify if hardware acceleration is enabled?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/963/how-to-verify-if-hardware-acceleration-is-enabled)

^^^ here is a related post,  first thing to do is make sure **mesa-utils** is installed, which will provide **glxinfo** and **glxgears**.

```
glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"

glxgears
```

observe the reported frame rate every ~5 seconds from glxgears, compare to what should be expected and diagnose from there, should typically see 60 fps unless you have a high end gpu which then can be over 1000fps.  If direct rendering is NO then that's a problem and start there to make it report yes.

It is `xorg-x11-drv-nouveau` among the other `xorg-x11-drv-` rpms that are installed which are related to graphics/gui performance along with `mesa-*` installation.

A potential fix, which I do when RHEL gets corrupted by NVIDIA is to reinstall the linux *graphics drivers/libraries* via...

```
init 3
systemctl set-default multi-user.target   {for safety after reboot}
rpm -ev --nodeps     mesa*
rpm -ev --nodeps     xorg-x11-drv-nouveau
yum install mesa*  xorg-x11-drv-nouveau
dracut -vf
reboot

# log in
init 5
systemctl set-default graphical.target {if graphics are successful after doing init 5}

 # note - this is done in a work environment over ssh remote connection;
          if doing at the console on a home pc/laptop be sure that your
          repositories are working to provide the re installation of mesa and
          xorg* otherwise you run the risk of no graphics and inability to log bacck in.
```

Generally the Linux GUI {graphical user interface} in regards to GNOME workstation desktop... desktop menu popups and such... is never a problem in Linux regardless of gpu or cpu; when it is it's almost always because of some misconfiguration or the system is bogged down running other processes which you should look to kill/disable.  Also check in on the `tuned` system service, do a  `tuned-adm list` and do `tuned-adm active` to see the current profile, consider doing `tuned-adm profile latency-performace`.  If the active profile is something like `laptop-battery-powersave` then that's probably not the best choice if you want graphical performance.

the big thing that comes to mind is **laptop** so if the thing is sitting for example on your bed on a blanket preventing case cooling, the thing will overheat and then the cpu will be throttled and the thing will be slow, so you want to check if any kind of [cpu] thermal throttling is happening, if the laptop fans are running high speed that's often a sign, as well as it's running on AC power first for diagnosing speed/performance problems.